# Как преобразовать строку в CookieContainer?

Tags: c#, cookie

Есть строка, которая по сути представляет собой кукисы. Интересует вопрос преобразования этой строки в куки

```
Cookie recentlyVisitedAppHubs=233450%2C231430%2C48110%2C45760; Language=spanish; strInventoryLastContext=440_2; __utma=268881843.118202637.1372069740.1373472452.1373473085.10; __utmb=268881843.21.10.1373473085; __utmz=268881843.1373473085.10.4.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); rgTopicView_General_4312225=%7B%22828934913396342649%22%3A%221373450285%22%2C%22846939615003500718%22%3A1373473557%7D; timezoneOffset=7200,0; sessionid=NDExNjE1NDE5; Login=765611979917322708A9C768; steamRememberLogin=76561197991732272; __utma=268881843.118202637.1372069740.1373472452.1373473085.10; __utmb=268881843.22.10.1373473085; __utmc=268881843; __utmz=268881843.1373473085.10.4.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
```

///////////////////////

```
CookieContainer cooks = new CookieContainer();
            var str = "recentlyVisitedAppHubs=233450%2C231430%2C48110%2C45760; Language=spanish; strInventoryLastContext=440_2; __utma=268881843.118202637.1372069740.1373472452.1373473085.10; __utmb=268881843.21.10.1373473085; __utmz=268881843.1373473085.10.4.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); rgTopicView_General_4312225=%7B%22828934913396342649%22%3A%221373450285%22%2C%22846939615003500718%22%3A1373473557%7D; timezoneOffset=7200,0; sessionid=NDExNjE1NDE5; Login=765611979917322708A9C768; steamRememberLogin=76561197991732272; __utma=268881843.118202637.1372069740.1373472452.1373473085.10; __utmb=268881843.22.10.1373473085; __utmc=268881843; __utmz=268881843.1373473085.10.4.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)";

   var rez = str.Split(';');
        foreach (var item in rez)
        {
            var tmp = item.Split('=');
            Cookie cook = new Cookie(tmp[0],tmp[1]);
            cookieContainer.Add(cook);
```

Выводит ошибку

```
Дополнительные сведения: Параметр '{0}' не может быть пустой строкой.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если внимательно посмотреть на сообщение об ошибке, там есть пояснение:

```
The parameter '{0}' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: cookie.Domain
```

Понятно, что вы не задали домен, к которому относится cookie. Он задаётся либо в конструкторе `Cookie`, либо аргументом команды `Add`.

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
var domain = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
var rez = str.Split(';');
foreach (var item in rez)
{
    var tmp = item.Split('=');
    Cookie cook = new Cookie(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
    cookieContainer.Add(domain, cook);
}
```